# Discord.py rewrite returning wrong message

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to make my discord bot do a small form. However, when I enter "N", for No, I instead get the answer I would have gotten had I entered "Y" ( for yes). Can anyone help?

```
@client.command()
async def shad(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Do you like Pugs(Reply with Y/N)")


    def check(m):
        return m.content in ["Y", "N"] and m.channel == ctx.channel

    await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    await ctx.send("Shad does love you")
    if "N" in ctx.content:
        await ctx.send("Shad does not love you")
```

Comment: You always send the `"Shad does love you"` message.  It should probably go in an `else` block after the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
@client.command()
async def shad(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Do you like Pugs?[Y/N]")

    awnser = client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
    if awnser in ['Y', 'y', 'yes', 'Yes']:
        #Do something
    else:
        #do something
```